# Sonar scanner is not able to create a report-task.txt file

Tags: sonarqube-scan

I am running sonar scanner from Jenkins Pipeline on multiple Java projects. All the projects using the below sonar command:

```
mvn  sonar:sonar \ 
-Dsonar.host.url=${sonar_host_url} \
-Dsonar.login="${SONAR_ACCESS_USERID}" 
 Dsonar.password="${SONAR_ACCESS_PASSWORD}"\
-Dsonar.projectKey="${scmreponame}" --batch-mode --quiet
```

but for one of the project I am getting the below error.

> "Unable to locate report-task.txt in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed ? "

I am not able to understand why only for one project it is not able to locate the `report.task` file?

Comment: I am voting to reopen since an example has been included. I'll leave it up to experts on the tag to cast a decisive vote.

Comment: yes I also am facing this issue with my UI code build which deals with the npm packages . Please update an answer once you have it with you